# How to restrict database write using hack "adb shell content insert --uri content://com.xxxxxx"

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-permissions

My Application's database is vulnerable and malicious code can inject false message to database.

How to make it secure from "adb shell content insert --uri content://com.XXX" ? --bind

I tried below in my manifest

```
    <provider android:name=".provider.MyProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.data"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="false"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

Thanks
As improvement I tried this as well (in manifest):

```
    <permission
     android:name="com.xx.yy_DB_WRITE_PERMISSION"
     android:label="xxyyDB"
     android:protectionLevel="signature" />

      <provider android:name=".provider.ZZProvider"
       android:writePermission = "com.xx.yy_DB_WRITE_PERMISSION"
       android:exported="false"/>
```

Still the ADB command from PC is able to inject message in my App's DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to sign and pre-load the application with following changes in manifest file and it worked:

```
<permission
 android:name="com.xx.yy_DB_WRITE_PERMISSION"
 android:label="xxyyDB"
 android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<provider android:name=".provider.ZZProvider"
 android:writePermission = "com.xx.yy_DB_WRITE_PERMISSION"
 android:exported="false"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

`<provider>` does not have any protectionLevel attribute. What you need is to protect your provider with a permission.

Define a `<permission>` and have your provider require it.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html

(`<permission>` does have a protectionLevel attribute, I think you mixed up the two elements)

Comment: I am still not able to get that right, could you elaborate please?

Comment: In what way are you not able to get it right? It helps a lot if you say what you tried and what the result was!